# Schengen visa for a non-EU citizen

Tags: visas, schengen, international-travel

I have obtained a work permit and residence permit for Malta. However, after obtaining the residence permit, my Schengen visa expires in a few days.

If I want to travel to another EU country for business or holiday. Can I apply for a Schengen visa in Malta from my country consulate? I am South African.

Answer (score 2):

Malta is part of the Schengen area.  Because you hold a residence permit issued by a Schengen country, **you do not need a visa to visit other Schengen countries.**

This is explicit in the [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407), at Article 6(1)(b), which describes the visa requirement thus (emphasis added):

> (b) they are in possession of a valid visa, if required pursuant to Council Regulation (EC) No 539/2001, **except where they hold a valid residence permit or a valid long-stay visa**

To be clear, the term "residence permit" is defined at Article 2(16)(a) (emphasis added):

> 16. ‘residence permit’ means:
>
> (a) **all residence permits issued by the Member States according to the uniform format laid down by Council Regulation (EC) No 1030/2002** and residence cards issued in accordance with Directive 2004/38/EC